# How to SortBy Min[Last]

Tags: sorting

I have a list of the form

```
{
{1, {3., ∞, ∞, ∞}},
{2, {1.,1., ∞, ∞}}, 
{3, {0.333333, 0.666667, ∞, ∞}}
}
```

and I would like to sort it by the minimal of the nested list inside each element, namely, `Min[{1.,1., ∞, ∞}]` etc. The result should be

```
{
{3, {0.333333, 0.666667, ∞, ∞}}
{2, {1.,1., ∞, ∞}}, 
{1, {3., ∞, ∞, ∞}},
}
```

I tried `SortBy[x,Min[Last]]` but the result is unexpected. Any help?

Comment: `SortBy[lis, Min[Last]]` works for me on V 12. Why did it not work for you?

Comment: @Nasser Not sure. It works in some cases but not in all cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
lst = {{1, {3., ∞, ∞, ∞}}, {2, {1., 1., ∞, ∞}}, {3, {0.333333, 0.666667, ∞, ∞}}};
```

You can use `Min@*Last` or `Min[Last@#] &`

```
SortBy[Min@*Last]@lst
```

> {{3,{0.333333,0.666667,∞,∞}},{2,{1.,1.,∞,∞}},{1,{3.,∞,∞,∞}}}

or

```
SortBy[Min[Last@#] &]@lst
```

> {{3,{0.333333,0.666667,∞,∞}},{2,{1.,1.,∞,∞}},{1,{3.,∞,∞,∞}}}